# Why does emacs sh-mode ignore indent-tabs-mode?

Tags: indentation

sh-mode won't care if indent-tabs-mode is on, it will still insert spaces instead of tabs! Can this be fixed?

Comment: What you describe doesn't match my experience, so please give more details, otherwise people will assume it's a misunderstanding of yours, or some local misconfiguration.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem starting from `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: Just press tab, then delete and you'll delete spaces, not tabs. As for me a tab is 4 spaces wide, meaning it is as big as for spaces but only a single press of backspace will delete all these 4 spaces (1 tab)

Comment: That's a different question then.  You'll find that a tab *was* inserted into the buffer, regardless of what the backspace key does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that `tab-width` and `sh-basic-offset` are not aligned.

`indent-tabs-mode` will only use tabs to indent up to multiples of `tab-width`, as otherwise it would indent too much.

That said, I find tabs bad for shell script indentation, as copying and pasting code from a script into a shell running in a terminal can be problematic.  I would recommend using spaces for shell scripts for this reason.

---

Edit: In this instance it was the backspace behaviour which was causing confusion.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>DEL</kbd> tells me:

```el
DEL (translated from <backspace>) runs the command
backward-delete-char-untabify (found in sh-mode-map), which is an
interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘simple.el’.

It is bound to DEL.

(backward-delete-char-untabify ARG &optional KILLP)

Delete characters backward, changing tabs into spaces.
The exact behavior depends on ‘backward-delete-char-untabify-method’.
Delete ARG chars, and kill (save in kill ring) if KILLP is non-nil.
Interactively, ARG is the prefix arg (default 1)
and KILLP is t if a prefix arg was specified.
```

Follow the link provided there and set `backward-delete-char-untabify-method` to `nil` so that it deletes a single character (which should be a tab) each time.

Comment: both them hos is 4

Comment: In that case, I can't reproduce your problem.  `indent-tabs-mode` works fine for me in `sh-mode` (and I used to use tabs in shell scripts a long time ago, so it was working in versions of Emacs as far back as I recall).

Comment: Answer updated to explain what backspace is doing.

Comment: good looking out. Should I change the title? If so any suggestions?

Comment: Your warning against tabs seems ok in general, but if the script uses a heredoc input with the `<<-` operator tabs MUST be used for it to function correctly.